# How to add an arbitrary namespace with PHP SoapClient?

Tags: php, namespaces, soap-client

How does one add an arbitrary namespace using PHP SoapClient?  The namespace does not actually get used in the request, but I think it is preventing my message from being properly consumed.

The WSDL is here : http://abr.business.gov.au/abrxmlsearchRPC/ABRXMLSearch.asmx?WSDL

The documentation for the particular message I want to send is here : http://abr.business.gov.au/abrxmlsearchRPC/(nye2ok45xc42vy552b15dx3t)/FormGenerator/ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocol.aspx.  I'm doing the SOAP request.

In the soap:Envelope, you'll notice a namespace called xmlns:types="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/encodedTypes", and you'll also notice it's not used in the soap:Body.

The message I'm sending is :  (newlines and indenting added for readability, authenticationGuid obfuscated for security)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocol>
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">company</name>
            <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string"></postcode>
            <legalName xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</legalName>
            <tradingName xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</tradingName>
            <NSW xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</NSW>
            <SA xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</SA>
            <ACT xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</ACT>
            <VIC xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</VIC>
            <WA xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</WA>
            <NT xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</NT>
            <QLD xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</QLD>
            <TAS xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</TAS>
            <authenticationGuid xsi:type="xsd:string">aaaa</authenticationGuid>
        </ns1:ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocol>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The response I get back is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/" xmlns:types="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">    
        <types:ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocolResponse><ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocolResult href="#id1" /></types:ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocolResponse>
        <types:Payload id="id1" xsi:type="types:Payload">
            <Request href="#id2" />
            <Response href="#id3" />
        </types:Payload>
        <types:ExternalRequest id="id2" xsi:type="types:ExternalRequest">           
            <ExternalRequestBody href="#id4" />
        </types:ExternalRequest>
        <types:Response id="id3" xsi:type="types:Response">
            <DateRegisterLastUpdated xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+11:00</DateRegisterLastUpdated>
            <DateTimeRetrieved xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-05-26T09:31:06.2949724+10:00</DateTimeRetrieved>
            <ResponseBody href="#id5" />
        </types:Response>
        <types:ExternalRequestNameSearch id="id4" xsi:type="types:ExternalRequestNameSearch">
            <AuthenticationGUID xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <Name xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <Filters href="#id6" />
        </types:ExternalRequestNameSearch>
        <types:ResponseException id="id5" xsi:type="types:ResponseException">
            <ExceptionDescription xsi:type="xsd:string">The GUID entered is not recognised as a Registered Party.

 Search GUID: </ExceptionDescription>
            <ExceptionCode xsi:type="xsd:string">WebServices</ExceptionCode>  
        </types:ResponseException>
        <types:ExternalRequestFilters id="id6" xsi:type="types:ExternalRequestFilters">
            <NameType href="#id7" />
            <Postcode xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <StateCode href="#id8" />
        </types:ExternalRequestFilters>
        <types:ExternalRequestFilterNameType id="id7" xsi:type="types:ExternalRequestFilterNameType">
            <TradingName xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</TradingName>
            <LegalName xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</LegalName>
        </types:ExternalRequestFilterNameType>
        <types:ExternalRequestFilterStateCode id="id8" xsi:type="types:ExternalRequestFilterStateCode">
            <QLD xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</QLD>
            <NT xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</NT>
            <SA xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</SA>
            <WA xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</WA>
            <VIC xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</VIC>
            <ACT xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</ACT>
            <TAS xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</TAS>
            <NSW xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</NSW>
        </types:ExternalRequestFilterStateCode>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It looks like the consumer has completely disregarded the content of the message.  The only thing I can see that is missing from the example is the types namespace, which is included in the response.

Thus, I'm thinking that if I can arbitrarily add the types namespace to the request, it may have better luck.

If anyone could tell me how to do that, or offer some other suggestion why the consumer ignores the values I've given in the request, that would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Extending SoapClient and overriding __doRequest() to add the namespace might actually be the solution, but I'd like a confirmation from someone who knows better.  It should be noted that the content of SoapClient::getLastRequest() is generated before modifications made by __doRequest(), so any modifications made via __doRequest() may need to be observed via a tcp dump.

Example code for this is

```
class ABRSoapClient extends SoapClient {

    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->loadXML($request);

        $dom->documentElement->setAttribute
        ('xmlns:types', 'http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/encodedTypes');

        $request = $dom->saveXML();

        error_log('Request in class:'.$request);

        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like overriding __doRequest() is the way to go.  With regard to the particular issue I was having, it turns out that the function I was calling, despite being on the WSDL, is only available via HTTP GET, and not SOAP.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the consumer has completely disregarded the content of the message"...

Comment: OK. so it sounds like you've resolved this issue?

Comment: @superspace, yes my underlying issue has been resolved, although the question still stands, kind of. It would be good to get a verification from someone who knows better that overriding __doRequest() is the best way to add an arbitrary namespace, regardless of the reasons for doing so.  Something I did see mentioned is that the content for SoapClient::getLastRequest() is generated before the __doRequest() action, so you'll need something like Wireshark if you actually want to know what went out on the wire. I'll update the description accordingly.

Comment: What is your expected response from the request?

Comment: @superspace, I ended up contacting the department who maintain the web service.  Even though the request type was available in the WSDL, they will only service it, if it has been received in the format of a HTTP GET.  I ended up using an alternative service call in their WSDL, and didn't need to manually add the namespace.