# PHP Akamai SOAP Exception

Tags: php, soap

I am making a SOAP request and it successfully return the function list which you can call.

I am calling PurgeRequest method and receiving following error

> Exception: class com.idoox.soap.DemarshallException: Type in schema
>   differs from type in SOAP message - expected
>   string@http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema; got
>   Map@http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"

I tried with SOAP UI and get the successful response id. But, my PHP request is failing..Can some one tell me what this error is about and how to resolve this. one reference say it is because of passing the empty array but I am sure that parameter is not empty.

```
if(class_exists('SoapClient'))
{
    $client = new SoapClient('https://ccuapi.akamai.com/ccuapi.wsdl',
                    array(
                    'trace' => 1,
                    'exceptions' => 0,
                    'features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE
                    )
    );
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    try {

        $purgeResult = $client->purgeRequest($username,$password,'',$opt,$url);
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e){
        echo "Exception\n";
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($purgeResult);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me, but I'm not logging in (of course). I get normal SOAP exceptions:

```
 Exception: class com.idoox.soap.DemarshallException: Dimensions not found in array type
```

when I pass an empty string in $opt, or

```
  object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
     ["resultCode"]=>
     int(301)
     ["resultMsg"]=>
     string(29) "Invalid username or password."
     ["sessionID"]=>
     string(16) "17F1327329982356"
     ["estTime"]=>
     int(-1)
     ["uriIndex"]=>
     int(-1)
     ["modifiers"]=>
     NULL
}
```

when I pass empty arrays in $opt and $url.

Anyway, your issue seems to be due to different SOAP xsd headers. The service expects http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema header, your script seems to be passing http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap.

Service WSDL defines it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<definitions name="PurgeRequest"
    targetNamespace="http://www.akamai.com/purge"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.akamai.com/purge"
    xmlns:purgedt="http://www.akamai.com/purge"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

You need to make sure your client respects this and sets it properly.

**Please post output of your**

```
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

(right after

```
var_dump($purgeResult);
```

)
mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://www.akamai.com/purge" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:purgeRequest>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">ee</name>
      <pwd xsi:type="xsd:string">rr</pwd>
      <network xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
      <opt SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
      </opt>
      <uri SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
      </uri>
    </ns1:purgeRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

see, this request features xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

Also make sure you are using right SOAP version

```
'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1
```

and your __doRequest() method in SOAP extension is not overriden to send custom headers, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132394/how-to-add-an-arbitrary-namespace-with-php-soapclient).

Comment: I think <opt> in your response is string whereas in mine it is <opt xsi:type="ns2:Map">
<item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">email-notification</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">myemail@test.com</value></item></opt>....Any idea how to correct this?.

Comment: Could you please update the post with the output of your var_dump($client->__getLastRequest()); ?